# What do I do with the pygame_master folder after running setup.py( OSX)?

Tags: macos, python, github

I downloaded Pygame from GitHub because the pip3 download method resulted in high CPU usage. So after downloading it, I ran setup.py and a folder 'Pygame_master' was created in my downloads folder. However, when I try 'import Pygame' it says there is no such module. Is there somewhere specific I should put the folder?

EDIT: When I run print(sys.path) one of the results is '/Applications/Python 3.7/pygame-master' so now I have no clue why this wouldn't be working.

Answer (score 0):

Python can only find Pygame if it is in the Python3.7 folder in Applications. Because it is instead in Downloads, python can’t find the module. Try moving pygame-master to `/Applications/Python3.7`